# allowing user to select from a list using the index location

Tags: python, list, dictionary, input

My apologies up front if I haven't asked this question correctly, it is my first time asking here.

I have a script that works currently, but I am trying to improve it.

I create a dictionary of days of the week and against each value I allow the user to input which meal they would like to eat on that day. However, at present I require the use to type their selected option from a list, which must match exactly. for instance "Szechuan pork stir-fry" - it is easy to make a typo here. Rather than manage the typo i'd like to make it easier for the use to make their selection from the list e.g. by selecting a key from a dictionary or an index location from the list - I am having trouble getting either of those to work though.

my code looks like this right now:

```
for d in week_meals:
    try:
        answer = input(f"What would you like to eat on {d}? options are {week_meals_list}")
        week_meals_list.remove(answer)
        week_meals[d] = answer
    except ValueError:
        print("That isn't an option!")
        answer = input(f"What would you like to eat on {d}? options are {week_meals_list} type {week_meals_list.index")
        week_meals_list.remove(answer)
        week_meals[d] = answer
```

I have tried to create a dictionary by doing something like the below but I cannot figure out how to set the key for each item to increment up by 1:

```
week_meals_dict = {}

for k in range(int(days)):
        week_meals_dict[k] = None
```

but then I really cannot figure out a way to iterate through each key while simultaneously iterating through a list in parallel. is this even possible?

this got me thinking it might be easier to just ask the user to input the index location within the list but I can't figure that out either.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...

not really sure I fully understand why it works but this does seem to:

```
for k in range(int(days)):
        week_meals_dict[k] = week_meals_list[k]
```

I can maybe even clean this up but I am happy with it for now

Comment: As a note, you can iterate through a list of dictionary keys using some_dict.keys(). So in the future if you want to iterate through the keys and a list in parallel you can use: for i,j in zip(som_list, some_dict.keys()):

Answer (score 0):

```
week_meals = {}
week_meals_list = ['meal1', 'meal2',]
for d in range(1, 8):
    meal = None
    while not meal:
        answer = input(f"What would you like to eat on {d}? options are {week_meals_list}")
        try:
            meal = week_meals_list[int(answer)]
            week_meals_list.remove(meal)
            week_meals[d] = meal
        except (IndexError, ValueError):
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [don't modify a list during iteration](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/).

It seems you're trying to match a meal for each day of the week.
You can iterate on the days:

```
week_meals_options = {1: "Chicken", 2: "Soup"} # Your dict containing choices mapped to the meal options
week_meals = {}
for day in week_days:
    while True:
        answer = input(f"What would you like to eat on {day}? options are {week_meals_options.keys()}")
        if answer in week_meals_options:
            week_meals[d] = week_meals_options.pop(answer) # Remove the option from the dict, and assign it to the day
            break
        else:
            print("That isn't an option!")
```